# Different IP address in ssh config and hostname for server

Tags: ip, hostname

I am sorry I am quite a newbie about networking, but here is my question.
I have a SSH config to connect to a server that looks like this:

```
Host dev
    User me
    Hostname IP_ADDRESS
```

When I connect to the server and I run the command:

```
hostname -I
```

I get a different IP address than IP_ADDRESS. How can it be possible and why?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: A server may not be aware of its true external IP address.

Comment: So that would mean the command shows me its internal address and that IP_ADDRESS is its external one?

Comment: Potentially. Hard to say without knowing the network setup and the IPs it's showing you and the IP you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's may be because of a lot of reaon, but I think in your case. That's because, your accessing it through a public IP of the company

Let imagine that you're home. Here is the schema of your connection

[your computer]--->--[your router]--->--[the internet]--->--[your company firewall]--->--[your company server]

You computer has probably an IP link 192.168.0.X on your private network

Your router has 2 IP 
 - 192.168.0.Y (to communicate with your home network)
 - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (a public ip address fixed or dynamic to communicate with the rest of the world wild web)

Your company firewall/router has also almost 2 ip (maybe more)
 - yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy (a public ip address  probably fixed to communicate with the rest of the world wild web) 
 - 10.0.0.1 (or something like that to communicate on the local network of your company)

And the server as almost 1 ip in the same range
 - 10.0.0.2 (let's imagine it's that)

What the administrator probably did is a NAT. It's a rules saying to the firewall that every connexion coming on a defined port of on the public IP of the firewall must be forwarded to the server.

So let's imagine that the public ip of the firewall is 110.12.23.34 and the port 8022 is forwarded to the server on his port 22.
That the ip of your server is 10.0.0.2

If you connect to 110.12.23.34:8022, you communicate in fact with your server as If you where connected localy on 10.0.0.2:22

So once on your server, when you make hostname -I. It return it's self address.

Comment: That makes sense, I did not think about the firewall. Thank you very much for your complete and clear explanation!

Comment: If there are a lot of possible reasons,  then what are the other ones, and why do you think it is this one?

Comment: There are other networking way of doing something like that. But this one is really the most common one. That's why I explained this one